# Passing dynamic dicts to python thread come out the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, dictionary

I'm trying to create a `dict`, then dynamically alter that `dict`, passing the `dict` to a thread. I boiled down the basic program to the following:

```
import threading

some_dict = {"1": "Spam", "2": "Bacon", "3": "Eggs"}
some_list = ["foo", "bar", "test", "test2"]


def threader(dict):
    print("start")
    thread_list = []
    i = 1
    while i < 4:
        print("adding...")
        some_dict[str(i)] = some_list[i]
        print(some_dict)
        new_thread = threading.Thread(target=printer, args=(some_dict,))
        thread_list.append(new_thread)
        i += 1
    print("dicts:")
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
    print("end")


def printer(dict):
    print(dict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threader(some_dict)
```

This code changes the dict, passing the changed dict as an arg to the thread. That thread is then added to the thread_list. Repeat three times, then run all three threads.

Unfortunately, once added to the thread_list, I keep having the most recent thread override the others. The above code prints:

```
start
adding...
{'1': 'bar', '2': 'Bacon', '3': 'Eggs'}
adding...
{'1': 'bar', '2': 'test', '3': 'Eggs'}
adding...
{'1': 'bar', '2': 'test', '3': 'test2'}
dicts:
{'1': 'bar', '2': 'test', '3': 'test2'}
{'1': 'bar', '2': 'test', '3': 'test2'}
{'1': 'bar', '2': 'test', '3': 'test2'}
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are the threads all the same?

Using Python 3.9.

Comment: I guess you want to pass a "copy" of dict to the threads: `new_thread = threading.Thread(target=printer, args=({k: v for (k, v) in some_dict.items()}, ))`

Comment: You say the "most recent thread" is overriding all the others, but it isn't. Your main thread has one `dict`. It updates it multiple times, but passes an alias to the same `dict` to each thread. And it doesn't launch any threads until all threads are constructed, so all of them launch after the final values are set in `dict` (which at least avoids a race).

Comment: @MauriceMeyer: No-op comprehensions are kinda pointlessly verbose/slow. A simple `some_dict.copy()` or `dict(some_dict)` would do the job more efficiently and less verbosely. Or `copy.deepcopy(some_dict)` if the values themselves might be mutated, not just reassigned.

Comment: Is the `dict` passed supposed to be progressively mutated (so the mutation for thread #1 remains for thread #2) or is it always supposed to be `some_dict` + one modification?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this worked! Though I'm really not sure how...

Comment: @ShadowRanger The dict changes each time the method is passed, then the changed dict is changed further so yes to your first question.

Also, MauriceMeyer had something that worked, I'm not sure how to implement the some_dict.copy(). Do I pass it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to just change:

```
new_thread = threading.Thread(target=printer, args=(some_dict,))
```

to:

```
new_thread = threading.Thread(target=printer, args=(some_dict.copy(),))
```

so each thread gets a shallow copy of the `dict` at the moment it's created. As written, you were passing aliases to a single shared `dict` to all the threads, and not launching any of them until the loop finished (at which point all the mutations were applied, and all threads saw the final state).

Answer (score 0):

Define a new dictionary, `d`, with `.copy()` every iteration of the loop to avoid overwriting the original dictionary. Also, avoid naming variables the names of built-ins:

```
import threading

some_dct = {"1": "Spam", "2": "Bacon", "3": "Eggs"}
some_list = ["foo", "bar", "test", "test2"]


def threader(dct):
    print("start")
    thread_list = []
    i = 1
    while i < 4:
        d = some_dct.copy()
        print("adding...")
        d[str(i)] = some_list[i]
        print(d)
        new_thread = threading.Thread(target=printer, args=(d,))
        thread_list.append(new_thread)
        i += 1
    print("dcts:")
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
    print("end")


def printer(dct):
    print(dct)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threader(some_dct)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, I plugged in your code as-is and it still prints the same.

Comment: @AnnZen: This doesn't work because `d = some_dct` isn't copying; `d` is just as much an alias of `some_dct` as in the OP's code.

Comment: @Chris Oh yeah! There needs tp be `.copy()`. My update should make it work now,

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks!